# ARM IRQ handler doesn't work properly in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I am developing a bare-metal ARM project using LPC2138 soc. I have written an IRQ interrupt handler for I2C. But it does not return properly. The handler is being called repeatedly for a single interrupt.

I have done a detailed debug analysis of this issue.

In the ARM7TDMI reference manual it's clearly mentioned the following thing.

[image]
But when I disassembled the code, I found that the code generated by GCC does not restore the CPSR resgister. Also an unknown value at last.

[image]

I have declared the IRQ handler like the following

```
void I2C0_IRQ_handler(void) __attribute__ ((interrupt("IRQ")));
```

Is s this a bug in GCC or have I done something wrong?

The compiler, assembler and linker flags I have used for building the project are:

```
CFLAGS := -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -g3 -Wall -I. -gdwarf-2
AS_FLAGS := -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -g3 -gdwarf-2
LD_FLAGS := -Wl,-Map,$(TARGET:%.hex=%).map -nostartfiles
```

Comment: In what way is it not working properly; what behaviour do you see compared to what you expect? Assuming `VICVectAddr = 0;` is clearing the interrupt, then this code is performing all 3 quoted steps appropriately (hint: read up on what `subs pc,...` actually does)

Comment: @Notlikethat When I2C start condition is sent interrupt should be generated. Its working. But after the interrupt routine, the control does not return to the interrupted code. The step 2 is missing in the assembly code.

Comment: As I said, step 2 _is_ being performed in that code, by the `subs pc...`. Having gone away and found the LPC213x manual, I see that that write does ack the interrupt at the VIC, but the interrupt is apparently level-triggered and you're doing nothing to deassert it at the I2C controller end (see section 13.9). Hence when you return you're just immediately taking the same interrupt again, ad infinitum.

Comment: Post text as text, not images!

Comment: IDK this particular device, but `VICVectAddr` is likely wrong (peripheral register names are typically all-uppercase) or insufficient. OP should read the reference manual.

Comment: @Olaf I am not using any IDE for this project. I defined all required registers with proper address. I defined the name as VICVectAddr.

Comment: @sreeyesh: Where do I talk about an IDE?? If you defined the macros yourself, I'd first check them thrice (best with 6 eyes - no pun intended!)! And you should use the names defined in the reference manual/user's guide/etc. Best is to use the vendor-provided header in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your analysis has two fatal flaws: Firstly, you're looking at it from the perspective of the CPU core, and secondly, it's wrong.

Second flaw first, I'm not sure why the ARM7TDMI manual has such an oddly overly-specific wording (you can't realistically do all those things separately anyway) but all 3 aspects are performed by the `subs pc, lr, #4` line in your code. [`subs pc, lr` is specifically an exception return instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473m/dom1361289908769.html) - it atomically restores the CPSR from the SPSR and returns to the fixed-up LR address. Since the CPU's interrupt disable flags are in the CPSR, then assuming that the I bit in that SPSR value is clear (which you kind of expect, given that you took an IRQ to get here...), IRQs will also be unmasked automatically in the process.

Thus, *from the CPU core's point of view*, your code is already (by virtue of its final instruction) doing everything an exception handler needs to, i.e. it resumes execution at the same point and in the same state as when the IRQ happened - there's certainly nothing wrong with the compiler. What it *doesn't* do, though, is anything about the fact that the peripheral way beyond the core is still asserting its interrupt, therefore the next thing you do after returning from the IRQ is to happily take the same IRQ again immediately. Repeat ad infinitum.

You have at least gone beyond the core as far as the interrupt controller; writing to `VICVectAddr` [acknowledges the interrupt at the VIC](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0181e/Cihdeddf.html), but that merely frees the VIC itself up to prioritise any pending interrupts and deliver the next one, which since the external source is still asserted (and assuming no higher-priority IRQ has come in from elsewhere), is still the same one.

To actually *handle* the interrupt and make any progress, you need to service the I2C peripheral raising it. Section 13.9 of [the LPC213x manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10120.pdf) outlines what needs to be done for each interrupt condition, but in terms of clearing the asserted interrupt, you need to write the SIC field of I2C0CONCLR.

Comment: That really helped me to solve my problem and learn new things. From your answer I can understand the effort that you have put and time that you have spared for answering my question. Thanks a lot for that :) And of course my up-vote.